# I need to change my Menu items from href to something more responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hello, I need to change Menu items from href to something more responsive. Because now when I hover a menu item I can only select it when pressing on text, but when I press on some white space it just disappears and does nothing.

```
<div className="border-bottom border-primary">
                <div className="container NavBarOnTop">
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-white">
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/stickerList">
                            <img src={Logo} width="112" height="20" alt=""/>
                        </Link>
                        <h5 className="Menu_text">Monitoring Dashboard</h5>
                        <div className="dropleft">
                            <a className="offset-5" href="#" id="imageDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src={Menu_icon} width="20" height="20" alt=""/>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="imageDropdown">
                                <Dropdown.Item><Link to="/">Home</Link></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><Link to="/domains">Maintaining List</Link></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><Link to="/users">User Maintaining List</Link></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><Link to="/login">Login</Link></Dropdown.Item>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use class="btn" and use class, not className

Comment: @Grumpy its look like react, so yes, need to use `className`. About the problem class `btn` can be a solution, if the other styles given by this class is ok. if not, can give a custom style. `display:block` and `height:100%` should work

Comment: Thanks for the help!